# Why is JSON Data Not Inserting Properly

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to render local JSON data to the DOM using the following code, but it's not working. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any help.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="model-controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="clickMe" style="background-color: #000; color: white;" onClick="myObj()">Click ME</button>

</div>
<div id="demo"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

**model-controller.js**

```
var myObj =  JSON.parse("item-data.json", function(data) {return data});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data; 
};
myObj();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function gets a string that represents a json encoded object, and not a path to a file.

If you need to parse a file you can use jquery to access the file

```
$.getJSON('item-data.json', function(data) {         
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data; 
});
```

Or get the content of the file using vanilla javascript and then `JSON.parse` it:

```
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("GET", "item-data.json", false);
   request.send(null)
   var json_obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = json_obj;
```

Comment: So this will get the data, parse it, and insert it into the div id "demo"?

Comment: Basically yes :)

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Getting a "function expected" error related to the function tied to onclick. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you wrap the code in my answer in a function and called that function `onclick`?

Comment: No. Would that fix it?

Comment: If you called an undefined function - you get errors for that :)

Comment: I just called the request() you defined above using the same code

Comment: that's not a function... you should **wrap** all of my code `function doSomething() { ...here my code...}` and in your `onclick` to call `doSomething`

Comment: Getting this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` parses a given string into a JS object. It doesn't load an external file though. [See this page for more info on the `JSON.parse` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

What you want to do is fetch the file with e.g. [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [`axios`](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).

```js
jQuery.get( 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD', ( data ) => {
  $( '#result' ).text( JSON.stringify( data, null, 2 ) );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```